# Why can I print out a privately inherited member of the Base class through a publicly inhterited method of the SubBase class?

Tags: c++, oop

**Student** inherits privately from **Person** class. That means that protected and public members and methods are gonna be treated as **private members and functions**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define COUT std::cout
#define ENDL std::endl

class Person
{
protected:
    std::string name;

public:
    void set_name(std::string _name)
    {
        name = _name;
    }
};

class Student : private Person
{
public:
    void display()
    {
        COUT << "Name: " << name << ENDL;
    }

    void set_Student_name(std::string _name)
    {
        set_name(_name);
    }
};

class GStudent : public Student
{
public:
    void set_GStudent_name(std::string _name)
    {
        set_Student_name(_name);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    GStudent martin;

    martin.set_GStudent_name("Martin");
```

> Then, why does the line of code of below work? I had thought that it would just have threw an error because the GStudent publicly inherited method called `display()` is printing out a privately inherited method that doesn't belong to the GStudent class but it belongs to Student class.

```
    martin.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `display` is public from`Student`, which is a public base to `GStudent`, which `martin` is an instance of. So... why did you think `display` wouldn't be accessible? Or did I miss something trivial in the posted code? If so, please explain ? `display` isn't "printing out a privately inherited method", or any other method. It's dumping a protected instance variable `name` to `std::cout`.

Comment: "name" is private in Student, therefore inaccesible in GStudent because private methods and members can't be inherited. <code>display()</code> is printing out "name" (Student private class member) from GStudent, and I thought it wouldn't be possible because supposedly private members are not inheritable.

Comment: *"private members are not inheritable"* - that's incorrect. They're not *accessible* outside the space where they become private unless they're friended (which isn't the case here). `Student` can access `name`, so `display()` works. If you moved the as-is definition of `display` to `GStudent`, *then* it would fail, because `GStudent` cannot access `name`; the private inheritance of `Person` to `Student` locked that down. Regardless, don't confuse inheritance with accessibility. They're *very* different.

Comment: I'd upvote you if I could, I can't see an upvote button in Comments :( Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You never have to care about the *body* of a method to know if you can call it.

You can call `display` because it is a public member of a public base of `martin`. That line would still be legal if `Person::name` were made private. In that case, the error would be in the *body* of `Student::display`.

It would be nonsensical otherwise. Imagine if you were restricted to only accessing things with the same access control. You wouldn't be able to construct private members, the constructor is invoked from outside the class. You wouldn't be able to read private members, because eventually you are called by something outside the class. Everything would *have to be public* to be usable, so there would be no access control.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string name` is private in class `Student` (and therefore accessible) since it is protected in class `Person`.